# C# Live version not showing correct error response

Tags: c#, iis, error-handling

When debugging my page, and entering a wrong ID (for example) I'm getting the correct Error page which looks like:

[image]

However, on the live version I get this:

[image]

I tried comparing the configs, using the live on debug, however on my local version I can not reproduce the error message.

My colleague has told me this could have something to do with the IIS Settings, however I'm not familliar with that either.

Any suggestions or advice to show me to the right path is greatly appriciated.

Comment: `web.config` issue maybe? check the `customError` section on both of them?

Comment: @Hackerman Yes, I've taken the config of the Live version and used it for debugging. I'm still getting the 'correct' error message

Comment: I think I might got it. `<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly"/>` Edit: nope.

Comment: Juas....that is a classic....change it to `errorMode="Detailed"` and restarting your site should fix the issue.

Comment: You could use some help from here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rakkimk/2007/05/25/iis7-how-to-enable-the-detailed-error-messages-for-the-website-while-browsed-from-for-the-client-browsers/ and http://www.sherweb.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-error-pages-in-iis-7-5-with-asp-net/

Comment: @MamunReza Thank you, I'll take a look at it. @Hackerman, Sadly that isn't it tho. I want the customers to only see the error message, and when using `DetailedLocalOnly` they don't see the link that goes to the stacktrace. - But I've copied the LIVE config to the Test server, which then 'breaks' the page, so I know it's something in the Config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/NotFound.aspx"/>
</customErrors>`
```

to `<customErrors mode="Off">`... fixed it!